# Autoloader class "Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoLoader" not loaded

Tags: php, zend-framework2, autoloader

I'm writing a Zend Framework 2.3.1 Application using PHP 5.5.12

My application contains several modules, and in each module's Module.php i have

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoLoader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php'
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

that's the only indication that I saw that is related to ClassMapAutoLoader.

when I try to run the application i get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Loader\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Autoloader class "Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoLoader" not loaded' in /mnt/storage/home/ufk/work-projects/global-logic/project/xpogames/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php on line 85
```

any ideas why ?

Comment: Does it work if you comment out the class map autoloader section (leaving just the standard autoloader)?

Comment: I am seeing the same problem as you. I get these errors when I try to run the Doctrine-Module CLI to update my database schema. The funny thing is that I do not get these errors on my local machine, but I do once I move everything over to a staging server...

Comment: Found the problem. Adding Answer below.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as you, and I figured out what was causing the issue:

```
'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoLoader' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php'
    ),
```

Needs to be:

```
'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php'
    ),
```

Small L in Autoloader. We both camel cased when we shouldn't have. This cleared it up for me. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The Module.php autoloading has nothing to do with the ZF2 autoloading.

How do u installed ZF2? I think u installed it on your own and not used composer?

In ZendSkeletonApp are some examples, how to autoload ZF2 itself:
https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/init_autoloader.php

Include this part in your public/index.php
https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/index.php#L14

Comment: i installed ZF2 using composer. i checked and my init_autoloader.php and index.php are the same as in git.

Comment: If you installed it with composer, where should be file vendor/autoload.php and if it's included all should work. https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/init_autoloader.php#L19-L22

Comment: when I remove Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoLoader from getAutoloaderConfig the problem goes away.